# How to create a new version of an app in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, deployment

I have deployed a React app using Google app engine. I deployed through the cloudshell CLI by cloning my github repo. I have made a few changes and am trying to figure out how to deploy the new version of the app but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I have looked around in the "Versions" tab on App engine and see that I can split traffic once multiple versions are created. I read the documentation found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/testing-and-deploying-your-app?tab=node.js). I can see here how to split the traffic but not how to publish changes to a new version.

Comment: 1) Do you want to have multiple versions? 2) If you don't, then deploy your current version the same way you deployed the first version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NocommandLine mentioned in the comment,

If you don't want to have multiple versions of an app, you can deploy the current version of an app the same way you did for the first version. Also you need to be aware that the older version of your app will get [shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown:%7E:text=You%20deploy%20an%20updated%20version%20to%20the%20service.).

If you want to have multiple versions of an app, You can check with this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-apps)

> The steps for deploying subsequent versions of your app, including creating additional services, are almost identical to the deployment steps covered in this task. If you want to replace the current version that is running in your App Engine application or if you want to add additional services, you can deploy new versions after making a few modifications to your configuration files.

> Check the [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-apps#example_deploying_additional_versions) for how to deploy additional versions to your App Engine application. Remember, after deploying your versions, you need to [configure their traffic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/migrating-splitting-traffic).